# Why did my question get closed as "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question entitled '[DESCRIBE command yields incoherent Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550010/describe-command-yields-incoherent-display)' (tag: PHP/MySQL) has been closed by a moderator (Kev) on the following 'grounds':

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened

Strangely, my question was closed after a user (Dai) seemed to have perfectly understood it and tried to provide a solution —unfortunately an uneffective one. Thus the question (a very detailed one with code and screenshots) remains unanswered.

So, my NEXT QUESTION is:

1. How come a moderator rules out a question as being meaningless [see cit. hereabove] whereas a helpful user understands it right away?
2. How can one oppose such arbitrary decisions?

Although I have so far come accross helpful and gentle users on this site, is this sort of kicking-out usual? If not, I suggest moderator Kev should review my initial question, give it a thorough thought and open it.

Since this post if of COLLECTIVE INTEREST in its scope, I don't dare think it will be zapped in turn.

Comment: I can only assume that perhaps `http://bluevortex.zapto.org` went down, no longer displaying any of the images in your question. I have now changed those to stack.imgur, hopefully ensuring this will not happen again.

Comment: Well, in a sense this post has been zapped in turn, taken to a better place :)

Comment: I cast a final vote to reopen and also downvoted - for the php code posted as image instead of text, [as pointed in one of comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550010/describe-command-yields-incoherent-display#comment16976502_12550010)

Comment: It's funny how you complain about someone not understanding your question, when you appear to have in turn not understood the comments to that question. Posting incredibly poor quality images of text was probably enough for people to cast a close vote, even if your image host wasn't down. People **like to answer** *high quality* questions. If you offend their senses as soon as they open it, they are going to pay you in kind.

Comment: Obnoxious.  Crack a faq or two.

Comment: @jmort253. I do not know who you are but you seem prone to teaching lessons. Is he not a untalented teacher he who says that if the answer was wrong then the QUESTION was wrong? You must have attended rhetoric classes in an Orwellian university. I say… Now, what is more, the original motive for dismissing me was: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened". Quod erat demonstrandum.

Comment: @Leigh. I wonder… Did YOU take a look at my initial question? Those who did and gave an answer (as Dai did — and thanks again to him) seemed to have no grievance. I could not earnestly believe you did take a look. After all you may have such an abstract mind that you don't need to —if need be.

Comment: @ALL. I have already made it clear I am a newcomer here —and it is a well-know fact that newcomers must learn what others already know but should not take for granted. 1) I had no means to suspect my screenshots were not uploaded on SA's server; 2) by checking my initial question one can tell screenshots are key to expounding the problem; 3) I have no clue what being "downvoted" means and I am not running for President: I have used this site for assistance (and I may share my own expertise with some other users someday) —it is my only quest. It's high time we focussed on technicalities.

Comment: @BriceCoustillas You're welcome. Next time just use SO's image uploading functionality. Should the images go down then, then it's not just you. :)

Comment: @Bart: Image uploads are not available to new users (one needs a reputation of 10).

Comment: @eggyal Which the OP had at the time. His rep has dropped since.

Answer (score 10):

> How come a moderator rules out a question as beeing meaningless [see cit. hereabove] whereas a helpful user understands it right away?

From that question (and this comment has been there for two days):

> The images in your question no longer exist, perhaps you could fix this and then I can re-open your question? Thanks. – Kev ♦

When your question depends on external resources to be understandable, and those resources go away (even if they then apparently come back later), some people won't be able to understand the question.

Don't make your question depend on external resources unless you really have to. If you have code, then insert the code in the question instead of inserting a *picture* of code.

Answer (score 3):

First, it doesn't look like your post was deleted, just closed. Closure is a temporary state that is intended to give you time to fix the problems with your question. Think of this like submitting a question on a forum where a moderator must read and approve your post before it's seen. Except here, we do it backwards, we push your post out first, and if we see problems, we push it back into the queue until it's ready to be published as a great, awesome question, once you've edited it into shape.

It looks like Bart used the closure period to fix your post for you, and it now has 2 of the 5 reopen votes it needs to be reopened.

With that said, You actually answered your own question and hit the nail on the head in regards to why your question was closed as "not a real question":

> Strangely, my question was deleted after a user (Dai) seemed to have perfectly understood it and tried to provide a solution —unfortunately an uneffective one. Thus the question (a very detailed one with code and screenshots) remains unanswered.

If the user gave you an answer that completely misses the point, that's sort of a sign that he really *didn't* understand your question. This implies that your question *was* difficult to understand, ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or overly broad, which is why it was closed.

Because Stack Overflow strives to be a resource of knowledge beyond just the original asker and answerer, it's important that questions asked be crystal clear, so that others searching for a similar problem can find it; your questions should benefit the N future visitors just as well as it benefits you. Hope this helps!